# Conditional initiation of group of beans by property

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

In my spring boot application I have many beans that responsible for monitoring.
Today, each one of them is annotated with:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="enable.monitor", havingValue="true")
```

This way the monitoring is completely configurable, and I can turn it on and off from the properties file.
The thing that I don’t like in this solution is that I must add this long annotation to each bean. I’ve wondered if there is a more elegant way to achieve this configurable monitoring. Maybe by annotated all the beans with some new annotation, say `@Monitoring`, and somehow tell spring to initiate them base on the property, is it possible?
Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create your own custom `@Monitoring` annotation as it follows:

```
Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="enable.monitor", havingValue="true")
public @interface Monitoring {
}
```

This can be applied afterwards to other beans.